# separar por virgulas uma coluna dentro de um array

Tags: php

queria separar cada nome por virgulas dentro de um array, tentei assim mais nao consegui

```
echo '<h1>'.$nomeTemporada.'° Temporada</h1>';

if(isset($_GET['id_temporada'])){

    $id = $_GET['id_temporada'];

}

$episodios = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `episodios` WHERE `id_temporada` = '$urlE[4]' AND `slug` = '$urlE[1]' AND `audio_temporada` = '$urlE[3]'");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($episodios)){

    $idTemporada = $res['id_temporada'];
    $nomeEpisodio  = $res['nome_episodio'];
    $slugTemporada = $res['slug'];
    $slugEpisodios = $res['slug_episodios'];
    $episodioTemporada  = $res['episodio_temporada'];
    $audioTemporada = $res['audio_temporada'];

    if(isset($urlE)){

        $episodioAtual = $urlE[2];

        $ep = [rtrim(''.$nomeEpisodio.'',',')];
        var_dump($ep);

        foreach ($ep as $palavra){

            if($episodioAtual == $palavra){

                $palavra = preg_replace('/[-]/ui', ' ',  $palavra);
                            echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-transform:capitalize;color:red;">'.$palavra.'</a>'.PHP_EOL;

            }else{

                echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-transform:capitalize;">'.$palavra.'</a>'.PHP_EOL;

            }
       }
}
```

**resultado esperado**

```
$ep = ['adeus-longos-dias','entranhas','diga-isso-ao-sapos']...
```

[image: var]

Comment: Separar por vírgulas dentro de um *array*? Como seria isso? Poderia colocar o resultado que espera obter?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss editei a pergunta com oque espero fazer

Comment: Por partes: `$nomeEpisodio` tem o nome de apenas um episódio ou de todos? Se for de apenas um, esse trecho está dentro de um laço de repetição? Se sim, ele **deveria** estar na pergunta também. Pela imagem, os nomes dos episódios estão em texto corrido, como "Adeus Longos Dias", mas no resultado esperado consta "adeus-longos-dias". Precisará ser feita essa conversão ou você colocou errado em algum lugar? Isso também poderia fazer parte da pergunta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss consegui, era so falta de atençao, so troquei as variaveis   `$nomeEpisodio` por `$slugEpisodios`

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` não resolveria?